# How to overrides some functions in HashMap.java

Tags: hashmap, overriding

1)Reading the code of [HashMap.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html). In line 762, the annotation says *subclass overrides this to alter the behavior of put method*. However, the function *void addEntry(int,K,V,int)* is a private function. How can it be overrided by a subclass?

```
             /**
  758        * Adds a new entry with the specified key, value and hash code to
  759        * the specified bucket.  It is the responsibility of this
  760        * method to resize the table if appropriate.
  761        *
  762        * Subclass overrides this to alter the behavior of put method.
  763        */
  764       void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
  765           Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
  766           table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<>(hash, key, value, e);
  767           if (size++ >= threshold)
  768               resize(2 * table.length);
```

2) In line 746 and 753, the two functions *recordAccess* and *recordRemoval* remain empty. So how can a subclass override these two functions?

```
             static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
  688           final K key;
  689           V value;
  690           Entry<K,V> next;
  691           final int hash;

                ...

                 /**
  742            * This method is invoked whenever the value in an entry is
  743            * overwritten by an invocation of put(k,v) for a key k that's already
  744            * in the HashMap.
  745            */
  746           void recordAccess(HashMap<K,V> m) {
  747           }
  748   
  749           /**
  750            * This method is invoked whenever the entry is
  751            * removed from the table.
  752            */
  753           void recordRemoval(HashMap<K,V> m) {
  754           }
  755       }
```

Comment: `addEntry` seems package-private, not `private` to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These methods are *not* `private`.

The accessibility when not specified is so called "package private". In particular, these methods *can* be overridden by other classes *in the same package*. The reason is *probably* that the Java authors want to be sure they can change/rename/replace this method anytime without breaking any application. When you are not sure that the API is good, it makes a lot of sense to keep those parts "package private", gather some experience with extending the class this way, and once you are sure the API is going to stay that way you can still make them public later on. However, you can't make them `private`, otherwise your own classes would also not be allowed to extend them!

To get a *true* `private` method, you should use the keyword `private`. Without any specification, the default is this so called "package private", and for public interfaces it even is public when nothing is specified.

If you are using eclipse, try Ctrl+T on the method name to see if any class overrides them.

Comment: so, the user is supposed to not subclass `HashMap` and override these methods? What is the rationale behind it?

Comment: The rationale probably is just: these parts of the API *may change across Java versions*, and overriding them might make your application then incompatible with future Java versions. I figure you are allowed to subclass `HashMap`, but *not* use these methods as they are not considered "stable API". Plus, probably a *delegate* is the better pattern to use than subclassing.